# How can I run dotnet on ubuntu without using sudo?

Tags: command-line, permissions, sudo, dotnet

I've been trying to update the permissions so that I can run a command (specificially `dotnet restore`). I'm not sure if this issue is specific to running `dotnet`, or if it is more generic.

I can run the command using `sudo dotnet restore`, however I want to be able to run this command without `sudo`.  This is because **I want to execute these commands via a CI tool (Jenkins), and I don't want that tool to have access to root commands.** . The Jenkins user is unable to run `dotnet restore` (because of the errors below) or `sudo dotnet restore` (because it doesn't have root access).

When I run **without** `sudo`, I have the following errors from `dotnet restore`:

```
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.104/NuGet.targets(104,5): error : Access to the path '/{file_path_to_project.csproj}/obj' is denied. 
[{file_path_to_project.csproj}]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.104/NuGet.targets(104,5): error :   Permission denied [{file_path_to_project.csproj}]
```

I've been trying to update the read and write permissions for my user on the `/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.104/NuGet.targets` file, and the `{file_path_to_project.csproj}` directory, but so far I still get the same errors.  Does it have something to do with the `/obj` directory? – When I run `ls` the `obj` file is not shown.

How can I update the permissions so that I can access these files without running `sudo`?

I created a `/etc/sudoers.d/dotnet` file to see if it would enable `dotnet` to be run without needing to call `sudo`.  I added the following contents:  `{myusername} {myhostname} = (root) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/dotnet`. However, this still required me to run `sudo` before `dotnet restore` to get the correct output.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76517/discussion-on-question-by-fuzzi-how-can-i-run-dotnet-on-ubuntu-without-using-sud).

Comment: Would you please [edit] and clarify about the CI tool you're using? What is it, how does it operate? If you can run `dotnet restore` via it, why can't you do the same with `sudo dotnet restore` *even without* it having root permissions?

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to use `mono` instead of `dotnet`. It's an open source implementation of the .NET framework and doesn't require root permission to run. It supports almost all of the .NET 4.7 features (see https://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/compatibility/ for exceptions).